# Logstash stopped after reading msg from elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I'm using logstash and elastic.
Giving input as elastic and output as Kafka. 
When starting logstash it reads all msgs from elastic, sending it to Kafka as expected.
But it stopped once processed all msgs. 
Not listening for future msgs. Is there any configuration to keep the logstash up and running??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question with your pipeline configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a schedule within your configuration file, i.e.

```
schedule => "* * * * * *"
```

If we wanted a job to run four times per day, the syntax would be the following:

```
schedule => "0 */6 * * * /logstash-config.conf"
```

This means every 6th hour starting from 0, i.e. at hour 0, 6, 12 and 18 the job would run.

Comment: I need to use the Cron and listen for every 3 second. I used Cron in the logstash elastic search input plugin. But the Cron starts only from minute.                  Eg:"* * * * *".  Is there an option to include seconds in the Cron??

Comment: I'm looking at the doumentation on cron and am seeing an option for seconds. [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/trigger-schedule.html#schedule-cron]

Comment: the reference is for elastic. My requirement is for logstash. Logstash doesn't have seconds